# Reverse engineering your own code c++

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

I have a compiled program which I want to know if a certain line exist in it. Is there a way, using my source code, I could determine that?

Tony commented on my message so I'll add some info:

1. I'm using the g++ compiler.
2. I'm compiling the code on Linux(Scientific)/Unix machine
3. I only use standard library (nothing downloaded from the web)
4. The desired line is either multiplication by a number (in a subfunction of a while group) or printing a line in a specific case (if statement)

I need this becouse I'm running several MD simulations and sometimes I find my self in a situation where I'm not sure of the conditions.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Do you have debug symbols embedded?

Comment: @Tony, I'm sorry for the lack of information but I mainly wanted to know what term to search for and if it possible at all. I'll edit my message for the information though it is not needed right now.

Comment: Why don't you just compile the source file in question the way you want it, and use that result?  Otherwise you don't really know what you have; that line you are hunting for might not be the only difference.  At the risk of sounding harsh, one is supposed to be careful when doing science experiments.

Comment: @Ira your are correct, the thing is that the simulations are running for about 1 week at a time and sometimes I'm not sure about a minor line...

Comment: @Tony I actually wish you keep it. There is no shame in admitting I was wrong or you pointing this out. This might come in handy for newbies.

Comment: @Yotam: -1 **Don't be unsure**.  If you write a science paper including results from your simulations, and say you were unsure, you'll get slammed by the reviewers much worse than my remark.  If you fail to say you were unsure, and people find out later, your reputation will be damaged.  This is not a place to make a mistake.

Comment: @Ira, again you are correct. The issue is that I'm toying around with simulations  so I will be sure about the right conditions, I want to know what are good condition for my run and what factor has an effect. Naturally for publishing, this is not sufficient but this is only the beginning of the research.

Comment: @Yotam: that you've edited in extra information and said it was at my request should give such newbies the same insight... just trying to make sure they've less to wade through when they're interested in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[objdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump)** is a utility that can be used as a [**disassembler**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler) to view executable in assembly form.
Use this command to disassemble a binary,

```
objdump -Dslx file
```

Important to note though that disassemblers make use of the symbolic debugging information present in object files(ELF), So that information should be present in your object files. Also, constants & comments in source code will not be a part of the disassembled output.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**

Use source code control and keep track of which source code revision the executable's built from... it should write that into the output so you can always cross-reference the two, checkout the same sources and rebuild the executable that gave you those results etc..

**Discussion**

> The desired line is either multiplication by a number (in a subfunction of a while group) or printing a line in a specific case (if statement)
>
> I need this becouse I'm running several MD simulations and sometimes I find my self in a situation where I'm not sure of the conditions.

For the very simplest case where you want all the MD simulations to be running the latest source, you can compare timestamps on the source files with the executable to see if you forgot to recompile, compare the process start time (e.g. as listed by ps) with the executable creation time.

Where you're deliberately deploying multiple versions of the program and only have the latest source, then it gets pretty tricky.  A multiplication will typically only generate a single machine code instruction... unless you have some contextual insight you're unlikely to know which multiplication is significant (or if it's missing).  The compiler may generate its own multiplications for e.g. array indexing, and may sometimes optimise multiplications into bit shifts (or nothing, as Ira comments), so it's not as simple as saying 'well, it's my only multiplication in function "X"'.  If you're printing a specific line that may be easier to distinguish... if there's a unique string literal you can search for it in the executable (e.g. `puts("Hello")` -> `strings program | grep Hello`, though that may get other matches too, and the compiler's allowed to reuse string literal sequences so "Well Hello" might cater to your need via a pointer to 'H' too).  If there's a new extern symbol involved you might see it in `nm` output etc..

All that said (woah)... you should do something altogether different really.  Best is to use a source control system (e.g. svn, cvs...), and get it configured so you can do something to find out which revision of the codebase was used to create the executable - it should be a FAQ for any revision control system.

Failing that, you could, for example, do something to print out what multipliers or conditions the progarm was using when it starts running, capturing that in your logs.  While hackish, macros allow you to "stringify" their parameters, so you can log and execute something without typing all the code twice.  Lots of other options too.

Hope some of that helps....

Comment: ... and the compiler may even optimize the multiply away if it knows enough about the value of the operands, or it may move the multiply outside a loop, or...  You just can't count on finding it, unless *you* know an awful lot about it.  Managing the compilation process in a tracable way seems a much better solution.

Comment: Shouldn't I open another question about "best way to keep MD data" or something and put that answer there?

Comment: I think that the best thing to do is create a source copy for each simulation and compile it just before the run. I need to check with our HPC stuff to see if I can add the compilation to the Que.

Comment: @Yotam: new Q - sure, if you feel you want more insight on that. BTW - don't assume something as terse as "MD" means the same thing to people outside your field - to me it means "market data", but I'm not confident that's what you mean, and even if it is it's better to spell it out at least once. And yes - if your MD isn't huge, it may be good to store versions of it in the same source control system....